# HTTP 503 Service Unavailable. IIS 8

Tags: windows, http, iis-8

After installing Helicon Zoo in IIS to deploy python django app on IIS I ve got with other applications, which were deployed before and working, HTTP 503. Logs give next information (for DefaultWebSite):

**A listener channel for protocol 'http' in worker process '100' serving application pool 'DefaultAppPool' reported a listener channel failure.  The data field contains the error number.**

Other apps give the same warnings and errors. Please HELP.

**Update**:
I have uninstalled Helicon Zoo and deployed site with Apache, now it works perfectly.

Comment: Could anyone help...

Comment: Check permissions on the folder it's trying to read? I've seen this when I haven't set AppPool perms on the site folder for normal IIS operation. Also, restart IIS to make sure.